# Creating list item dynamically in chrome extension

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html, google-chrome-extension

I am new to jquery. I am making a chrome extension which gets some `DOM` element from - say for example, any price of product from flipkart.

So, i want to make a list of each product's price user is viewing at the moment. I am able to get the price. But what i want to do, is make a closable list in my `popup.html` file, when i get the product price.

It's like, price should be dynamically displayed or added as a closable list when i get the price's data. I don't know how it can be achieved. I am confused here. Can you guide me please?

```
myfile.js
```

```js
var ulcontainer = $('<ul></ul>');
     $('body').append(ulcontainer);
     $ ('ul').css('list-style','none');
 
 for (var i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
   dothis();
 }
function dothis()
{
 $('ul').append("<li></li>")

 var imgdiv = $('<div></div>').text("this is imgdiv"); /// prod

 var detaildiv = $('<div></div>').text("this is detailsdiv"); ///price of prod
 var closebtndiv = $('<div></div>').text("this is closebtndiv");
 $('li').append(imgdiv,detaildiv,closebtndiv,"<br>");
 $('li').css({'padding':'20px'});  
 $('div').css({'display':'inline','padding':'20px'});
 
}
```

i tried to do this by making a function and run it in for loop..if it works fine then i can call the same function when the data arrives and make a list item.
But some how the o/p of this function is weird.

Comment: show what you have tried?

Comment: see my code shown above